# WebSphere Portal portlet crazy threading

Tags: multithreading, websphere, portlet, websphere-portal

We are dealing with an issue in our WebSphere Portal solution.
It's a stand-alone application server, running WebSphere Portal on top of WebSphere 6.0 and all the stack is installed by another IBM product: WCL - Workplace Collaborative Learning (an e-learning plataform). It's a Windows Server 2003 install, btw.

The issue is that when we hit a portal page with a portlet/web clip, the JVM process fires a thread, which never dies. This happens always when a new user (new session) hits that page.

It's an out-of-the-box install, with no customization at all, except that portlet page, created using the WebSphere Portal back-office with a 3-click wizard.

Here's a picture of the thread ramp up (the user bar represents one hit at at time, not simultaneous users):

[alt text http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/7638/threadind.png](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/7638/threadind.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a thread dump and see exactly what those threads are doing when they are hung... chance are they are waiting on something.  You run a kill -3 on UNIX but under windows it is a little bit different, see this link here:

[Thread Dump](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_dump.html)

When you run it it will generate a file.  The file will contain each thread running in the system.  The thread numbers should correspond to the threads that you are getting in your logs telling you that they are hung.  Post up some of the hung threads and I will take a look at them.

Regards,

Michael.